# OpenCV Sobel Filters resulting in almost completely black images

Tags: c++, opencv

I am having some issues with my sobel_y (and sobel_x, but I figure they are having the same issue) filter in that it keeps giving me an image that it basically only black and white.  I am having to rewrite this function for a class, so no I cannot use the built-in one, and had it working, minus some minor tweaks because the output image looked a little strange with still being black and white even though it was supposed to be converted back.  I figured out how to fix that, and in the process I messed with something and broke it and cannot seem to get it back to working even with the black and white image output only.  I keep getting a black image, with some white lines here and there near the top.  I have tried changing the Mat grayscale type (third parameter) to all different values, as my professor mentioned in the class that we are using 32 bit floating point images, but that did not help either.

Even though the issue occurs after running the Studentfilter2D, I think it is a problem with the grayscaling of the image, although whenever I debug, it seems to work just fine.  This is also because I have 2 other filtering functions I had to write that use Studentfilter2D, and they both give me the expected results.  My sobel_y function is shown below:

```cpp
// Convert the image in bgr to grayscale OK to use the OpenCV function.  
// Find the coefficients used by the OpenCV function, and give a link where you found it.
// Note: This student function expects the matrix gray to be preallocated with the same width and
// height, but with 1 channel.
void BGR2Gray(Mat& bgr, Mat& gray)
{
    // Y = .299 * R + .587 * G + .114 * B, from http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor
    // Some extra assistance, for the third parameter for the InputArray, from http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#inputarray
    // Not sure about the fourth parameter, but was just trying it to see if that may be the issue as well
    cvtColor(bgr, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY, 1);
    return;
}
// Convolve image with kernel - this routine will be called from the other
// subroutines!  (gaussian, sobel_x and sobel_y)
// image is single channel.  Do not use the OpenCV filter2D!!
// Implementation can be with the .at or similar to the
// basic method found in the Chapter 2 of the OpenCV tutorial in CANVAS,  
// or online at the OpenCV documentation here: 
// http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat-mask-operations/mat-mask operations.html 
// In our code the image and the kernel are both floats (so the sample code   will need to change)
void Studentfilter2D (Mat& image, Mat& kernel)
{
    int kCenterX = kernel.cols / 2;
    int kCenterY = kernel.rows / 2;
    // Algorithm help from http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html
    for (int iRows = 0; iRows < image.rows; iRows++)
    {
        for (int iCols = 0; iCols < image.cols; iCols++)
        {
            float result = 0.0;
            for (int kRows = 0; kRows < kernel.rows; kRows++)
            {
                // Flip the rows for the convolution
                int kRowsFlipped = kernel.rows - 1 - kRows;
                for (int kCols = 0; kCols < kernel.cols; kCols++)
                {
                    // Flip the columns for the convolution
                    int kColsFlipped = kernel.cols - 1 - kCols;
                    // Indices of shifting around the convolution
                    int iRowsIndex = iRows + kRows - kCenterY;
                    int iColsIndex = iCols + kCols - kCenterX;
                    // Check bounds using the indices
                    if (iRowsIndex >= 0 && iRowsIndex < image.rows && iColsIndex >= 0 && iColsIndex < image.cols)
                    {
                        result += image.at<float>(iRowsIndex, iColsIndex) * kernel.at<float>(kRowsFlipped, kColsFlipped);
                    }
                }
            }
            image.at<float>(iRows, iCols) = result;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void sobel_y (Mat& image, int)
{
    // Note, the filter parameter int is unused.
    Mat mask = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 1,
        0, 0, 0,
        -1, -2, -1) / 3;
    //Mat grayscale(image.rows, image.cols, CV_32FC1);
    BGR2Gray(image, image);
    Studentfilter2D(image, mask);
    // Here is the documentation on normalize http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize
    normalize(image, image, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
    cvtColor(image, image, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    return;
}
```

Like I said, I had this working before, just looking for some fresh eyes to look at it and see what I may be missing.  I have been looking at this same code so much for the past 4 days that I think I am just missing things.  In case anyone is wondering, I have also tried changing the mask values of the filter, but to no avail.

Comment: Studentfilter2D()? Can you show us your code?

Comment: @BalajiR added Studentfilter2D.  It is just the 2D convolution of the image with a specified mask/kernel.

Comment: apart from the broken `image.at<float>` (see answer below), you cannot do this in-place on an 8bit-uchar image. since the sobel generates values exceeding 255 and also negative values, you need a separate output Mat with a higher, signed range, e.g. CV_16S or CV_32F even.

Comment: Yes, if you see the above edits, I have already changed and tested that, but to no avail.

Comment: your code does not show that.

Comment: I have changed the grayscale image to be CV_32FC1.  I have also added the normalize function under the Studentfilter2D, which I may be using wrong, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it based on the documentation.  We have not talked about normalization in class.   I have also tried just using the original image and not using the grayscale extra, but that also did not work.

Comment: that won't work, since the gray img will be just overwritten by cvtColor(). you will have to explicity convertTo(CV_32F) after that

Comment: After doing the cvtColor, I will have to convert it to 32F?

Comment: I am starting with a 32bit floating point image, that is what is being passed in.  And after doing the covert to grayscale, the image still says it is FLOAT32 in the Image Watch debugger.

Comment: Okay, after looking more into the normalize function, I realized I was using it wrong.  Now I seem to be getting an image  that doesn't really have any edge detection, it just looks like it is negated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that are worth mentioning.

The first is that you are not taking proper care of the type of your matrices/images.
The input to `Studentfilter2D` in `sobel_y` is an 8-bit grayscale image of type `CV_8UC1` meaning that the data is an array of `unsigned char`.
Your `Studentfilter2D` function, however, is indexing this input image as though it was of type `float`. This means it **is picking the wrong pixels to work with**.

If the above does not immediately solve your problem, you should consider the range of your final derivative image. Since it is a derivative it will no longer be in the range [0, 255]. Instead, it might even contain negative numbers. When you try to visualize this, you will run into problems unless you first **normalize your image**.
There are built in functions to do this in OpenCV if you look around in the documentation.

Comment: Okay thank you! Your first point is what I already assumed was wrong and had tried using the CV_32FC1, but that didn't work so I didn't keep it. I will try normalizing it and see if that fixes it.

Comment: So I made some changes and tested them, but cannot seem to get anything different, e.g. the normalization isn't working still, but not sure if I am even using the function correctly.  I have added my changes above.

Comment: This answer, along with realizing that I had part of my Studentfilter2D overwriting my image as it was being processed turned out to be the issue.  Thanks for the help